# Facebook feed dialog with fb.ui in iframe causing parent frame to postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

I've got an iframe with the FB.ui javascript  feed dialog. When the feed dialog is called, it causes the parent page of the iframe to postback (and it scrolls to the top).

How can I call it without the fb.ui causing a postback of the parent page (or at least avoiding the scrolling to the top)?

Code below...

```
 <div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


        FB.init({
            appId: '<appid>',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });



    function posttowall(thename, thedescription, thelink) 
    {
        FB.ui({ method: 'feed', name: thename, description: thedescription, link: thelink }, 
        function (response) { alert('done'); }
        )
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Are you calling posttowall from a button click?